# How to modify eqnarray?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm currently writing a maths undergrad dissertation using Texmaker, and when I use `eqnarray`. It keeps justifying all of the equations to the right but still in the center?

How do I change this so that they align on the left (but still in the center)? I.e. so all the equals signs align? For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{eqnarray}
    \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} = 0\\
    \Rightarrow \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}}=0\\
    \Rightarrow \displaystyle\int_b^a \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}} \,dx= constant = C\\
    \Rightarrow f'(x) = \dfrac{C}{\sqrt{1-C^2}} = m\\
    \Rightarrow \quad f(x) = mx+ \text{constant}
  \end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Avoid `eqnarray`!](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/madsen.html) Use the corresponding environments from »[amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)«.

Comment: Thank you so so much for helping me everyone!! Think I've got the hang of it now :-) !

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you have accepted the best answer. (I clearly prefer [Thorsten's](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163042/15874) or [my own](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163041/15874) answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `eqnarray` environment is intended to a "left-center-right" aligned array of equations. You must mark the alignments with `&` signs (change every `=` to `&=&` ):

```
\dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} &=& 0\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}}&=&0\\
\Rightarrow \displaystyle\int_b^a \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}} \,dx= constant &=& C\\
\Rightarrow f'(x) = \dfrac{C}{\sqrt{1-C^2}} &=& m\\
\Rightarrow \quad f(x) &=& mx+ \text{constant}
\end{eqnarray}
```

But `eqnarray` is not a good solution for arrays of equations, because spacing between the equation terms is inconsistent with spacing in other mathematical expressions. Use the `amsmath` package and `align` environment
(here, only one `&`is needed in every equation):

```
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} &= 0\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}}&=0\\
\Rightarrow \displaystyle\int_b^a \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}} \,dx= constant &= C\\
\Rightarrow f'(x) = \dfrac{C}{\sqrt{1-C^2}} &= m\\
\Rightarrow \quad f(x) &= mx+ \text{constant}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Please give full MWEs instead of code snippers as answers.

Answer (score 6):

The `alignat` environment from »[amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)« makes alignment easier. And »[physics](http://ctan.org/pkg/physics)« simplifies the typesetting of derivatives.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
                      && \dv{x}\,\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} &= 0 \\
    \Rightarrow\qquad && \dv{x}\,\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}} &= 0 \\
    \Rightarrow\qquad && \int_b^a \dv{x} \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}}\,\dd x &= \text{constant} = C \\
    \Rightarrow\qquad && f'(x) &= \frac{C}{\sqrt{1-C^2}} = m \\
    \Rightarrow\qquad && f(x) &= mx+\text{constant}
  \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Further information about advanced math typesetting can be found in the »[Math mode](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode)« document.

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\differential[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}#1}
\newcommand*\diff[3][\differential]{\frac{#1#2}{#1#3}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{alignat}{2}
  &&\diff{}{x}\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^{2}}}
  &= 0\\
  &\Rightarrow
  &\diff{}{x}\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^{2}}}
  &= 0\\
  &\Rightarrow\quad
  &\int_{b}^{a} \diff{}{x}\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^{2}}} \differential{x}
  &= \text{constant}
   = C\\
  &\Rightarrow
  &f'(x)
  &= \frac{C}{\sqrt{1-C^{2}}}
   = m\\
  &\Rightarrow
  &f(x)
  &= mx + \text{constant}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

Note: Remove the `\mathrm` if you don't want the differential `d` to be upright.

(Remember to [Avoid `eqnarray`!](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf).)

**Update**

If you want vertical arrows between the equations, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*\differential[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}#1}
\newcommand*\diff[3][\differential]{\frac{#1#2}{#1#3}}
\newcommand*\arrowDown{\ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow]}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  &&\diff{}{x}\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^{2}}}
  &= 0\\
  \arrowDown
  &&\diff{}{x}\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^{2}}}
  &= 0\\
  \arrowDown
  &&\int_{b}^{a} \diff{}{x}\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^{2}}} \differential{x}
  &= \text{constant}
   = C\\
  \arrowDown
  &&f'(x)
  &= \frac{C}{\sqrt{1-C^{2}}}
   = m\\
  \arrowDown
  &&f(x)
  &= mx + \text{constant}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Answer (score 3):

you are already using `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{align}
                \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}       &= 0\\
    \Rightarrow \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}} &=0\\
    \Rightarrow \displaystyle\int_b^a \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}} \,dx &= constant = C\\
    \Rightarrow f'(x) = \dfrac{C}{\sqrt{1-C^2}}                  &= m\\
    \Rightarrow \quad f(x)                                       &= mx+ \text{constant}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

or

```
  \begin{align}
    &&\dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} &= 0\\
    \Rightarrow &&\dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}} &=0\\
    \Rightarrow &&\displaystyle\int_b^a \dfrac{d }{dx} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}} \,dx &= constant = C\\
    \Rightarrow &&f'(x) = \dfrac{C}{\sqrt{1-C^2}} &= m\\
    \Rightarrow &&\quad f(x) &= mx+ \text{constant}
  \end{align}
```

The `&` character is used for the horizontal alignment. See http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf

By the way: `eqnarray` has the syntax: `left & middle & right`